# Converting img src data to octet-stream

Tags: javascript, rest, base64

I am working on a REST call that has a body that accepts a *application/octet-stream*.

I need to use this API to send an image that from a "src" atributte from an HTML  element:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAA ... AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
```

How can i convert this type of data to send trough this API?

API:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        method: 'POST',
        data: imgData,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
                //Do something
        }
        error: function(x, e, s) {
                //Do something
        }
});
```

I tried to use the function provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript). It completes the call, but the file on the other part is not saved as a image file.